# why tracker.current.Interaction.geodata return null value in sitecore if GeoIp service is running

Tags: geo-location

I am using sitecore 8.2 Update-1, I have issue with GeoIp. On my system GeoIp service is already running.

[image]

And if I am access IP address in Experience explore then return all GeoIp value like same as in below screenshot

[image]

But I am trying access Geo Data from `GeoIpManager.GetGeoIpData` like

[image]

So `GeoIpManager.GetGeoIpData` is return null.

What should I do to resolve this error and what should we need check configuration for same issue

Comment: Do you have xDB enabled and Tracking turned on? I believe those are required for GeoIp to work.

Comment: Yes I have enabled both.

Comment: I've not seen this myself, but doing a little searching seems to indicate that the first time you call it you don't always get a result. Can you try `Thread.Sleep()`ing for 5 seconds and making the call again to see if it's populated after a second request?

Comment: But In my scenario, i am getting null response every time.when i am trynig to access geo data from GeoIpManager.GetGeoIpData